# How are checkpoints created in a custom object detector with tensorflow 2 model zoo?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

I've currently been training some models from the tensorflow2 object detection model zoo following the tutorial from https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html.

One of my doubts arised when I was looking to export my model from a checkpoint that had the total loss that I was looking for. Nevertheless, I found that I had 16 checkpoints (just the last five of them) but only 1500 steps elapsed. I have to mention that I passed a flag to save a checkpoint every 100 steps. So I'm wondering if:

It creates an initial checkpoint, let's say the checkpoint 0 and if I want to export a model from the 1400th step I should take the 15th checkpoint

or

It creates a "placeholder" for the future checkpoint, i.e. If training process is currently in step 1500 it prepares to store the next checkpoint. I should then take just the 14th checkpoint.

I leave an image of reference,

[image]

[image]

In this example, I have 16 checkpoints but only 1500 steps have elapsed. I've chosen to save a new checkpoint every 100 steps. If I want to export a new model from the step 1400, should I export the 14th or 15th?

Any help would be much appreciated.